# Angular AOT with Webpack

Tags: angular, webpack, aot

Is there any documentation out there on how to get Angular4 working with webpack with AOT?  I checked a number of articles but they dont seem to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `@ngtools/webpack` plugin fir this.

Install the plugin and use like this

```
{
  test: /\.ts?$/,
  use: '@ngtools/webpack',
}
```

and add to plugin

```
new ngtools.AotPlugin({
    tsConfigPath: path.join(process.cwd(), 'tsconfig.json'),
    entryModule: path.join(process.cwd(), 'src/app/app.module#AppModule')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The Angular CLI uses webpack: https://cli.angular.io/

It's pretty nice to use to start projects, the only downside to using the CLI is that you have little (no) control over the webpack configuration.

Comment: As an addition you could use `ng eject` to move from an Angular CLI based project to a webpack one. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/eject